# How to get intersecting products from different categories

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown in the below pic, its a stripped version of bigger table.

[image]

**Question**

I have to get the products in category 9030 and 1993, so in this case it should show 1 row. But when I execute below query it gives null as result.

> SELECT * FROM catalog_category_product WHERE category_id='1993' AND
>   category_id=9022

So expected output would be 1 row with product_id 33839, is there any way to intersect the results.

I am not very much that familiar with MySQL queries, please advise.

Comment: use or instead of and

Comment: category_id cannot be both values at the same time, use an OR or IN ()

Comment: but it will give all the products in these categories, not intersected result

Comment: X cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time!?!??!??! But it could be 1 OR 2 maybe or better still `category_id IN (1993, 9022)`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get **intersected** result:

**Using `NOT IN`:**

```
SELECT 
 C1.product_id
FROM catalog_category C1
WHERE C1.product_id IN 
(SELECT 
   C2.product_id 
 FROM catalog_category C2
 WHERE C2.category_id = 9030 
)
AND C1.category_id = 1993
```

**Using `INNER JOIN`**:

```
SELECT 
    C1.product_id
FROM
    catalog_category C1
INNER JOIN catalog_category C2 ON C1.product_id = C2.product_id
WHERE   C1.category_id = 9030 
AND C2.category_id = 1993;
```

**Using `EXISTS`:**

```
SELECT 
 C1.product_id
FROM catalog_category C1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM catalog_category C2 
  WHERE C2.category_id = 1993
  AND C1.product_id = C2.product_id
)
AND C1.category_id = 9030
```

Comment: Solved my problem, used the second method.. accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A single value cannot be 1993 AND 9022 it can only be one of them

So you could use

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_product 
WHERE category_id=1993 OR category_id=9022
```

Or better still

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_product 
WHERE category_id IN (1993, 9022)
```